# How to avoid an incompatible types error with a non parameterless constructor in a generic container?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I get `E2010 Incompatible types: 'TDerivedFrame' and 'TBaseFrame'` on the following code:

```
type
  TBaseFrame = class(TFrame)
  end;

  TDerivedFrame = class(TBaseFrame)
  end;

  TContainer<T: TBaseFrame> = class
  private
    FFrame: T;
  public
    property Frame: T read FFrame;
    constructor Create;
  end;

constructor TContainer<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FFrame := TBaseFrame(T).Create(nil);
end;

var
  FTab: TContainer<TDerivedFrame>;
```

Using only `T.Create(nil)` causes `E2568 Can't create new instance without CONSTRUCTOR constraint in type parameter declaration`.

As far as I know you can only create a constructor constraint with a parameterless constructor.

What is the correct way to do this?

PS: The code compiles when I remove the variable which makes me think this is a compiler error?!

Edit: I understand the E2010 error, but even with `T(TBaseFrame(T).Create(nil))` it doesn't work. This compiles, but causes an access violation at runtime:

```
type
  TBaseFrame = class(TFrame)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TDerivedFrame = class(TBaseFrame)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TContainer<T: TBaseFrame> = class
  private
    FFrame: T;
  public
    property Frame: T read FFrame;
    constructor Create;
  end;


constructor TBaseFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

end;

constructor TDerivedFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

end;

constructor TContainer<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FFrame := T(TBaseFrame(T).Create(nil));
end;

var
  FTab: TContainer<TDerivedFrame>;
begin
  FTab := TContainer<TDerivedFrame>.Create;
end.
```

Comment: I would believe T would be instances of objects, so you would need something like 
  TBaseFrameClass=Class of TBaseFrame;
  TDerivedFrameClass=Class of TDerivedFrame;
which wouldn't help in your approach working with Generics

Comment: @bummi Since TBaseFrame has a virtual constructor (from TComponent) it does help in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FFrame := T(TBaseFrameClass(T).Create(nil));
```

is the correct way to do this.

You'll need

```
type 
  TBaseFrameClass = class of TBaseFrame;
```

Your compiler error is because you are *instantiating* a type, `TContainer<TDerivedFrame>`. When you instantiate that type you ask the compiler to deal with

```
FFrame := TBaseFrame(...);
```

where `FFrame` is `TDerivedFrame`. If you wrote that code out without generics you'd understand the compiler error.

So, the compiler is behaving correctly here, but the issue of instantiation is catching you out. It's only at the point of instantiation that the compiler error becomes apparent. Without instantiation, of if you had instantiated `TContainer<TBaseFrame>` there would be no compiler error.

The AV is because you were casting `T` to be an instance rather than a class.

Comment: I've added an example that causes the AV to the end of the question.

Comment: I still can't see an AV in there. The generics code is fine and the creation of FFrame is fine.

Comment: `FFrame := T(TBaseFrame(T).Create(nil))` causes an AV, `FFrame := T(TComponentClass(T).Create(nil));` works ...

Comment: Ah, I see. I understand. Silly me. I can't believe I didn't see it!

Comment: So I have to cast to the class that declares the virtual constructor to make this work?

Comment: TComponentClass would be fine also. But in my view it's more sensible to cast to class of constrained class, class of TBaseFrame here.

Comment: I'm very sorry it took so long for me to see that.

Comment: No problem, at least the cause is clear now. I confused types with instances :).

Comment: so my comment was ignored :-(

Comment: @bummi I didn't understand it and got confused by the TDerivedFrameClass part. But you were spot on about instance vs class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one:
   `TContainer<T:constructor, TBaseFrame> = class`